# Use FCM groups for A/B Testing

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, ab-testing

I am creating a solution that permit other app editor to sent notifications to their app through Firebase Cloud Messaging, and I want to develop the possibility to do A/B Testing.
I came across the groups syteme of FCM and, if that works, it would be a good way to separate audiences in two or three groups, as it is possible to register several devices at the same time in a group. However it seems to be designed to represent the devices of a single user, which means a small number of devices.
So my question is, can we still use FCM grouping with a large number of devices (in the tens of thousands) ? Or can they not be used this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. [Device Groups](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) have a limit of 20 tokens per group:

> The maximum number of members allowed for a notification key is 20.

High volume tokens in a group could be handled by [Topics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging) better.

Comment: Thanks. I missed this line.

Answer (score 1):

I realize you asked this question six month ago, but for anybody who is looking to A/B test their notifications using Firebase Cloud Messaging, this functionality is now directly built into the Firebase Notifications panel. I'd recommend [checking out the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/abtest-with-console), and heading right into the Notifications panel of the Firebase Console to start building your A/B test.